# Why does Firefox open my JSP webpage file as raw source code and not display the actual page?

Tags: jsp, firefox

I am running the Java Pet Store example and this is the top part of my "index.jsp" file :

```
<%-- Copyright 2006 Sun Microsystems, Inc. All rights reserved. You may not modify, use, reproduce, or distribute this software except in compliance with the terms of the License at: http://developer.sun.com/berkeley_license.html
$Id: index.jsp,v 1.20 2007-03-16 20:18:59 basler Exp $ --%>

<%@page contentType="text/html"%>
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*, com.sun.javaee.blueprints.petstore.model.CatalogFacade, com.sun.javaee.blueprints.petstore.model.Tag"%>

<%
try {
    CatalogFacade cf = (CatalogFacade)config.getServletContext().getAttribute("CatalogFacade");
    List<Tag> tags=cf.getTagsInChunk(0, 12);
    // since top 20 come from database or desending refCount order, need to reorder by tag name
    Collections.sort(tags, new Comparator() {
        public int compare(Object one, Object two) {
             int cc=((Tag)two).getTag().compareTo(((Tag)one).getTag());
             return (cc < 0 ? 1 : cc > 0 ? -1 : 0);
        }
    });    
%>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
        <title>Java Pet Store Reference Application</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./tag.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
```

....

Comment: Which raw source code do you see?

Comment: The code I posted here - when I click index.jsp I get this.  I did try renaming to "index.html" but it displays an incorrect page(looks like a skeleton with no graphics/functionality.)

Comment: @fvu - I'm supposed to be using the Glassfish server (JEE version 5, I believe ).  Hmm.. maybe this is it. Let me check what's up with it.

Comment: @Adel I once had a comparable problem with a Glassfish server where something went wrong during installation - it worked, except for the rendering of JSP's.  I solved it by reinstalling the server, so I never really analyzed what went wrong.  But all versions of Glassfish (1-3) are capable of rendering JSPs.

Comment: @fvu, Thanks so much! I'm almost there now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but I'll attempt to show what goes on to render a JSP.  Following that path, and analysis of domains/domain1/server.log (if your installation is using the default domain called domain1) might give you a hint on what's wrong.

Normally in a GF2 there's a file called default-web.xml in the domain's config directory.

It contains these snippets:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
```

The above code configures JSP support - of course it will fail if it cannot locate the servlet code, but that should be logged in server.log.

After that, the following snippets ensure that the above servlet is called to manage jsp's - one mapping for "classic" jsp's and one for "xml syntax" jsps.

```
  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


  <!-- ================ Built In Servlet Mappings ========================= -->


  <!-- The mapping for the JSP servlet -->
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Now, if for whatever reason these segments are missing in default-web.xml, jsp support will be inactive, and you'll get an effect like the one you describe because the file will be picked up by the default servlet, and will be handled as a static resource.

Comment: This is very helpful, and I'm reading the log now. Thank You Very Much!

Answer (score 6):

Maybe the server is not configured properly for serving JSP pages or maybe the mime/type is not configured properly for JSP pages.

Comment: He's probably serving the website as mime type `"text/plain"` instead of `"text/html"`

Comment: @Raynos no - I suspect that the server has a config issue that causes it to fail to see that it should compile the JSP and then run the compiled code, and that's long before stuff like mimetypes come in to play.

Answer (score 0):

This might be quite old but i have encountered this problem too, and its related to display a JSP page using the just the browser (the page is not hosted or managed by the server at the moment, in other words the server is off).

so this is a graphical explaination of what happens:

there is the page loaded with firefox showing just raw code/plan text
[image: img1]

there is the same page correctly loaded, for verification purposes its source code is visible to notice that both pages have the same code
[image: img2]

This problem happens because both pages have different file enconding, one is ANSI (the one who displays normally) and the other is UTF-8(the one who displays raw code). so to fix this, we need to:

1. open the problematic page with notepad
2. File > Save As..
3. Select ANSI in Encoding combobox
4. Select All Files in Save as type combobox
5. Open the page again to verify that displays correctly

[image: img3]

the page is correctly displayed
[image: img4]